# Stop sleep in Ubuntu Touch webapp

Tags: ubuntu-touch, webapps, webapp-development

How can I configure my webapp so the screen won't go to sleep when the app is open? This would be useful for the youtube webapp

Comment: https://open.uappexplorer.com/ < there is a tool in there"tweekgeek" that can let you keep an app running in the application settings feature of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the policy "keep-display-on" in the .apparmor file. This should be enough. See an example below:

```
{
    "template": "your-webapp",


    "policy_groups": [
        "networking",
        "webview",
        "audio",
        "video",
        "keep-display-on"
    ],


    "policy_version": 16.04
}
```

Comment: Can you expand upon this? How do we add the policy? Can you post an example `.apparmor` file?

Comment: Yes. I updated the post. Thank you